# How to make form fill and submit in bootstrap modal?

Tags: django, django-views, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I can't figure out what the problem is, please help. I have a button, when clicked, a modal window opens, in which a form for adding an entry is displayed, but when the "save" button is clicked, the page reloads, but nothing is saved.
I added my code below. If I make a form on a new page (`localhost:8000/add_department/7`), then the form is saved and everything works, but not in the modal window.

base.html:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-add btn-padding-left btn-add-department" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#button-department-add" data-url="{% url 'department_add' 7 %}"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add department</button>
    
    <div class="modal fade" id="button-department-add" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-bs-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content modal-department">
    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

add_department.html:

```
<form action = "" method = "post">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Add department</h5>
            <button class="btn-close" type="reset" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">
            <b>Press "save".</b>
            <br>
            <br>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {{ answer }}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-save"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary btn-cancel" data-bs-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Cancel</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Region, Department
from .forms import *
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
from .forms import *
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='login/')
    def department_add_view(request, pk):
        answer = 'test'
        template_name = 'add_department.html'
        form_class = DepartmentForm
        form = form_class(request.POST or None, initial={
            "region_id": pk
        })
        data = {
            'form': form,
            'answer': answer
        }
        if request.method == 'post':
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return render(request, 'add_department.html', {
                    'answer': 'Successfully'
                })
        return render(request, template_name, data)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from mainapp.views import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', home_view, name='home'),
    path('login/', login_view, name='login'),
    path('department_add/<int:pk>', department_add_view, name='department_add'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *


class DepartmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'region_id': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

script.js:

```
$('#button-department-add').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  let button = $(event.relatedTarget);
  let url = button.data('url');
  let container = $(this).find('.modal-department');
  container.html('');
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
  }).done(function(data){
    container.html(data);
  });
});
```